# How to give prototype method access to parent variables?

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

I have a little library that can perform methods on a specific DOM element. It looks a little like this:

```
//An accessor method for the library
window.$ = function(selector){
    var new_instance = new lib();
    return new_instance.init(selector);
}
//And the actual library...
function lib(){
    this.context = window;
    this.init = function(sel){
        this.context = document.querySelector(sel);
        return this;
    };
    this.addPlugin = function(name, fn){
        lib.prototype[name] = fn;
        return this;
    };
}
```

Like Prototype or jQuery, you select the element with a `$(_selector_)` call. To add a method to the library, you would use the `lib.addPlugin(...)` method. Unfortunately, when I add a method like so:

```
lib.addPlugin('foo',function(){
    console.log(this.context);
    return this;
});
```

The `THIS` keyword refers to `window`, not the original parent library instance. I don't know much about how all the prototype stuff works, but I am wondering if there is someway I can get around/fix this. I would like newly added methods to be able to reference the parent library's variables.

Comment: Your code works for me if I replace `lib.addPlugin('foo', ...);` with `$('body').addPlugin('foo', ...);` **[Try it](http://jsfiddle.net/mD6yM/).**

Comment: That's interesting. Do you know why it works in that case and not the other?

Comment: In your question, `addPlugin` is a method of an instance of `lib`, not a function on `lib` itself. If you modify it [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/uuDpv/), you can use `lib.addPlugin('foo', ...);` successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not redefine functions in the constructor, you are creating a closure every time you call `$`, which uses a lot of memory.

Anyways I didn't see any other problem other than addPlugin being an instance method instead of static method which I implemented like this:

```
function lib(){
this.context = window;
}

lib.addPlugin = function(name, fn){
  this.prototype[name] = fn;
  return this;
 };

lib.prototype.init = function(sel){
this.context = document.querySelector(sel);
return this;
};
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rAasm/

Comment: Which function is redefined in the constructor?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas `init` and `addPlugin` in the OP